# BundleConfig.cs using bootstrap.min.css

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

My `BundleConfig.cs` file looks like this (CSS):

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-switch.css",
                  "~/Content/datepicker.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-duallistbox.css",
                  "~/Content/fullcalender.css",
                  "~/Content/fullcalender.print.css"));
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

No where am I calling bootstrap.min.css, however, when I updated only the bootstrap.css file none of my changes were recognized.  I started to make the changes in the .min file and then I noticed my changes.

I get that the `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` takes all of the .css files and minimizes them, but I don't understand why I had to update the .min file for it to recognize my style changes.

I expected the `bootstrap.css` file to be minimized in memory and used that way.

Can someone explain why this is occurring?

Just for more information I'm using MVC5 in VS2013

Comment: You are not running in Release mode are you?

Comment: @Michel the OP has `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` set, which simulates what will happen in release mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you include `stylesheet.css` in an bundle and there is already a `stylesheet.min.css` file in your project, the optimization framework will use the `.min` file when `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations == true`.

It does the same thing for `script.min.js` files.

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; // when this is not false
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrap.css", // will look for bootstrap.min.css
    "~/Content/site.css", // will look for site.min.css
    "~/Content/bootstrap-switch.css", // will look for bootstrap-switch.min.css
    "~/Content/datepicker.css", // will look for datepicker.min.css
    "~/Content/bootstrap-duallistbox.css", // will look for bootstrap-duallistbox.min.css
    "~/Content/fullcalender.css", // will look for fullcalender.min.css
    "~/Content/fullcalender.print.css")); // will look for fullcalender.print.min.css
```

If you would rather have the optimization framework minify for you, just remove bootstrap.min.css from your project.

[From the docs](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification):

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
     bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                 "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
         // Code removed for clarity.
}
```

The preceding code creates a new JavaScript bundle named ~/bundles/jquery that includes all the appropriate (that is debug or minified but not .vsdoc) files in the Scripts folder that match the wild card string "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js". For ASP.NET MVC 4, this means with a  debug configuration, the file jquery-1.7.1.js will be added to the bundle. In a release configuration,  jquery-1.7.1.min.js will be added. The bundling framework follows several common conventions such as:

- Selecting “.min” file for release when “FileX.min.js” and “FileX.js” exist.
- Selecting the non “.min” version for debug.
- Ignoring “-vsdoc” files (such as jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js), which are used only by IntelliSense.

Comment: Thank you.  That seems to be a logical answer.  Is there any documentation to support this?

Comment: @webdad3 I have updated my answer with a reference from the docs on the asp.net site. Note the same applies to style bundles as script bundles.

Comment: To be clear, the bundler doesn't use the min version to avoid work. It's actually a safe-guard. Minification is not a perfect science and depending on the complexity of the source, certain minification protocols may cludge the contents of the file causing it to not work properly any more. By including a `.min` version, you're instructing the bundler to use your preferred minified source rather than create its own. It will still bundle this with everything else; it just excludes it from the minification cycle.